# Retorno a linha TEXT SVG

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

Estou a criar um text svg dinamicamente, e quero por um retorno a linha do meio das duas váriaveis quando imprimo. Experimentei com o "\n" e o "br" mas não me faz.

```
var text_h_fin = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
text_h_fin.setAttribute('x',10 );
text_h_fin.setAttribute('y', 20);
text_h_fin.setAttribute('fill', '#000');
text_h_fin.setAttribute('font-size', '14px');
text_h_fin.textContent = "1 linha" + "\n" + "2 linha";
svg.appendChild(text_h_fin);
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo visual do que queres fazer? Queres uma linha debaixo da outra?

Comment: Sim exactamente isso, mas não me está a funcionar. Onde imprimo: text_h_fin.textContent = "1 linha" + "\n" + "2 linha";

Comment: Essa quebra de linha é sempre no mesmo sítio ou dinamica? vais ter de fazer elementos diferentes para isso pois nõ há quebra de linha no text do svg.

Comment: Ah ok, então crio outro elemento. Obrigado @Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Você pode quebrar uma linha criando outro objeto `<text>` ou usando elementos `<tspan>` variando a posição (atributo) `dy` que é relativa:

```
<text x="10" y="20" fill="#000" font-size="14px">
    1 linha
    <tspan dx="18px">2 linha</tspan>
</text>
```

Assim você pode mover todo um parágrafo ou bloco de texto sem precisar mexer nas posições de cada linha.

Veja: http://www.argonavis.com.br/cursos/xml/x500/SVG%2005_Texto.pdf